# how to tikzpicture side by side without overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have 4 tikzpicture that I want to put them side by side in a one page width. But they overlap with each other. Can you please help me to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Calculation},
        height=8cm, width=15.5cm,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,
            0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,1.0},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={year 2016},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.15, 81.2)
            (0.2, 77.7)
            (0.25, 79.5)
            (0.3, 78.8)
            (0.4, 81.4)
            (0.5, 81.7)
            (0.6, 82.6)
            (0.8, 7.0)
            (1.0, 83.9)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Calculation},
        height=8cm, width=15.5cm,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.25,0.3,0.4,0.5,
            0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={year 2013},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.25, 85.7)
            (0.3, 56.1)
            (0.4, 21.9)
            (0.5, 30.9)
            (0.6, 62.73)
            (0.8, 80.69)
            (1.0, 22.55)
            (1.2, 30.84)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Rate},
        height=8cm, width=15.5cm,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,
            0.8,1.0,1.2, 1.6},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={Rate},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.3, 59.29)
            (0.4, 34.29)
            (0.5, 23.15)
            (0.6, 86.83)
            (0.8, 75.53)
            (1.0, 66.95)
            (1.2, 59.37)
            (1.6, 47.68)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Calculation},
        height=8cm, width=15.5cm,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.4,0.5,0.6,
            0.8,1.0,1.2, 1.6},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={year 2016},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.4, 23.54)
            (0.5, 36.05)
            (0.6, 73.67)
            (0.8, 43.0)
            (1.0, 95.35)
            (1.2, 34.30)
            (1.6, 27.60)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Rate}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, lose the subfigures.  Without captions, they serve no purpose.  Second, reduce the width (15.5cm *4 = 62.cm, or 31cm at scale=0.5).  width={.5\textwidth} at scale=0.5 works.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but it does not work in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Zarko put more effort into it, he left useless subfigures in.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}%
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Calculation},
        height=8cm, width={0.5\textwidth},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,
            0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,1.0},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={year 2016},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.15, 81.2)
            (0.2, 77.7)
            (0.25, 79.5)
            (0.3, 78.8)
            (0.4, 81.4)
            (0.5, 81.7)
            (0.6, 82.6)
            (0.8, 7.0)
            (1.0, 83.9)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Calculation},
        height=8cm,  width={0.5\textwidth},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.25,0.3,0.4,0.5,
            0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={year 2013},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.25, 85.7)
            (0.3, 56.1)
            (0.4, 21.9)
            (0.5, 30.9)
            (0.6, 62.73)
            (0.8, 80.69)
            (1.0, 22.55)
            (1.2, 30.84)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Rate},
        height=8cm,  width={0.5\textwidth},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,
            0.8,1.0,1.2, 1.6},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={Rate},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.3, 59.29)
            (0.4, 34.29)
            (0.5, 23.15)
            (0.6, 86.83)
            (0.8, 75.53)
            (1.0, 66.95)
            (1.2, 59.37)
            (1.6, 47.68)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
        \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Calculation},
        height=8cm, width={0.5\textwidth},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.4,0.5,0.6,
            0.8,1.0,1.2, 1.6},
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={year 2016},
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.4, 23.54)
            (0.5, 36.05)
            (0.6, 73.67)
            (0.8, 43.0)
            (1.0, 95.35)
            (1.2, 34.30)
            (1.6, 27.60)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%
    \caption{Rate}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: i left subfigure in *mwe* in hope that OP will learn that determining their widths is not trivial. of course in this particular case they are surplus :-).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

changes:

- widths of sub figures (it had to has width bigger from width of its content)
- `ylabel` has only the first graph
- increase scale to 0.6
- image width is decreased to 80 mm (before scaling)
- rotate `xtick label`
- common `axis` options are collected in `pgfplotsset`for this figure

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\pgfplotsset{% for this figure
        width=80mm,
        ybar, axis on top,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,
                          anchor=east},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        xlabel style={at={(0.5,-0.18)},
                          anchor=north},
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.3)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
                     },
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}
            }% end of common pgflotsset
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.26\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
        title={Calculation},
        symbolic x coords={
            0.15, 0.2, 0.25,0.3,
            0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,1.0},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        ylabel={Percentage (\%)},
        xlabel={year 2016},
            ]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.15, 81.2)
            (0.2, 77.7)
            (0.25, 79.5)
            (0.3, 78.8)
            (0.4, 81.4)
            (0.5, 81.7)
            (0.6, 82.6)
            (0.8, 7.0)
            (1.0, 83.9)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
        title={Calculation},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        symbolic x coords={
            0.25,0.3,0.4,0.5,
            0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2},
        xlabel={year 2013},
                    ]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.25, 85.7)
            (0.3, 56.1)
            (0.4, 21.9)
            (0.5, 30.9)
            (0.6, 62.73)
            (0.8, 80.69)
            (1.0, 22.55)
            (1.2, 30.84)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
        title={Rate},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        symbolic x coords={
            0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,
            0.8,1.0,1.2, 1.6},
        xlabel={Rate},
                        ]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.3, 59.29)
            (0.4, 34.29)
            (0.5, 23.15)
            (0.6, 86.83)
            (0.8, 75.53)
            (1.0, 66.95)
            (1.2, 59.37)
            (1.6, 47.68)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
       title={Calculation},
        bar width=0.4cm,
        symbolic x coords={
            0.4,0.5,0.6,
            0.8,1.0,1.2, 1.6},
        xlabel={year 2016},
                    ]
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=black!60] coordinates {
            (0.4, 23.54)
            (0.5, 36.05)
            (0.6, 73.67)
            (0.8, 43.0)
            (1.0, 95.35)
            (1.2, 34.30)
            (1.6, 27.60)
        };
        \legend{First Fix, Second Fix}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Rate}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

note:

- i commented package, which i havent
- image is very small, i suggest to consider to have only two, not scaled in line
- it  is not clear why you use  `subfigure` environments. the same result you obtained if omit them in between `tikzpictures` put`\hfill`